# How to copy file from temporary location to Application Container - Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am using UIDocumentPickerViewController to get file from cloud storage when Item is selected DidPickDocumentFromCloud is executed:

```
protected void DidPickDocumentFromCloud(object sender, UIDocumentPickedAtUrlsEventArgs e)
        {
            NSUrl[] temporaryFileUrl = e.Urls;
            NSUrl fileUrl = temporaryFileUrl[0]; 
            var demoPath = FileSystemHelper.Current.PDFStorageFolder.Path;
            var targetFile = Path.Combine(demoPath, documentName + ".pdf");
            pdfOutputUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(targetFile);                
            File.Copy(fileUrl.ToString(), pdfOutputUrl.ToString());
        }
// fileUrl = {file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/xxx- 
xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/tmp/com.xxx.xxx-Inbox/xxx.pdf}
```

Which throws a FileNotFoundException exception for "fileUrl". How should I copy file to application, so I can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution I need to use NSFileManager to copy the file.

```
        NSUrl[] temporaryFileUrl = e.Urls;
        NSUrl fileUrl = temporaryFileUrl[0];
        NSFileManager filemanager = new NSFileManager();
        var demoPath = FileSystemHelper.Current.PDFStorageFolder.Path;
        var targetFile = Path.Combine(demoPath, documentName + ".pdf");
        pdfOutputUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(targetFile);
        documentImageUrl = NSUrl.FromString(targetFile);
        NSError err = new NSError();
        filemanager.Copy(fileUrl, pdfOutputUrl, out err);          
        docPicker.DismissModalViewController(true);
```